# I'm creating a Python code to filter out values within a CSV, but values that I want to keep are being removed. What am I missing?

Tags: python, csv, filtering

I've been working with one of my advisors to create a python code that will:
1. remove the first 2 lines from a csv,
2. remove lines that contain a "Margin of Error" value in the Output column, and 
3. remove lines in which there is no value in the Workers 16 and Older column.

The CSV is formatted with four columns in the following order: Residence, Workplace, Output, Workers 16 and Older.

We have been able to complete all of the above goals successfully, HOWEVER, the code is removing lines that contain no value in the Workers 16 and Older column AS WELL AS any value over 3 characters. Any value that is 1,000 or greater is being filtered out, and I can't see where that would be happening in the code. Any help or suggestions?

Thank you!

```
import csv
with open('wyoming.csv','r') as csv_file:
    Oneline = csv_file.readline()
    Oneline = csv_file.readline()
    with open('Nicole_out4.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_out:
        mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        Oneline = csv_file.readline()
        Title_line = Oneline.split(',')
        Title_line[-1] = Title_line[-1][0:-1]
        print(Title_line)
        mywriter.writerow(Title_line)
        for Oneline in csv_file:
            testline = Oneline.split('"')
            test1 = len(testline)
            if test1 < 2:
                break
            for ea in testline:
                if len(ea) < 2:
                    testline.remove(ea)
                elif (ea[0]==','):
                    newea = ea[1:].split(',')
                    testline.remove(ea)
                    for eas in newea:
                        testline.append(eas)
                    if (testline[2] == 'Margin of Error') or (len(testline[3]) < 2):
                        break
                    else:
                        testline[-1] = testline[-1][0:-1]
                        mywriter.writerow(testline)
    csv_out.close()
csv_file.close()
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Quick note: when you leave the scope of the `with` statement the file is automatically closed so there is no need to call `close()` on `csv_out` or `csv_file`.

Comment: Can't help you solve this directly but if you want to sniff out the problem. Grab one of the problem rows, load only that as the data and then go through each step of your loop to see where exactly the behavior deviates from what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking too closely at your code, I feel like you're making it more complicated than it needs to be - that being said, I don't really have any idea what your CSV file actually looks like.

I imagine it looks something like this maybe (`data.csv`):

```
Residence,Workplace,Output,Workers 16 and Older

Bob'sHome,Bob'sWork,abc,
Tom'sHome,Tom'sWork,xyz,100
Joe'sHome,Joe'sWork,foo,1000
Tim'sHome,Tim'sWork,Margin of Error,10
```

Where the first line defines the column field names, and maybe the second line is empty. According to your filtering criteria, only the second and third entries (`Tom` and `Joe`) would make it past the filter, correct?

I suggest something like this:

```
def main():

    from csv import DictReader

    with open("data.csv", "r") as file:
        reader = DictReader(file)
        for line in reader:
            if line["Output"] == "Margin of Error" or not line["Workers 16 and Older"]:
                continue
            print(line)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
{'Residence': "Tom'sHome", 'Workplace': "Tom'sWork", 'Output': 'xyz', 'Workers 16 and Older': '100'}
{'Residence': "Joe'sHome", 'Workplace': "Joe'sWork", 'Output': 'foo', 'Workers 16 and Older': '1000'}
>>>
```

I'm a bit surprised that you aren't fully taking advantage of the `csv` module. Instead of using it for both reading and writing of CSV files, you only use it for the writing part. I like working with `csv.DictReader`s. It handles blank lines and the potential fieldnames automatically. Instead of printing the filtered lines, however, you would write them to a file.

Without seeing an excerpt from your actual CSV file, it's difficult to help more.